# Как передавать значение переменных на другие страницы

Tags: php

У меня есть вот такой код внутри страницы

```
$title = "Выбор диапозона";
require "Blocks/header.php";
print_r($_GET);

?>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Давай сыграем с тобой в игру угадай число, для начала выбери диапазон случайного числа </h1>

    <form action="Blocks/check_range_select.php" method="get">
        <label for="min">Введите минимальное число дипозона: </label>
        <input type="number" name="min" min="0" class="form-control"><br>
        <label for="max">Введите максимальное число дипозона: </label>
        <input type="number" name="max" min="0" class="form-control"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить данные" class="bnt btn-success">
    </form>
</div>
=

<?php
require "Blocks/footer.php";
?>
```

Далее, после ввода данных пользователем выполняется проверка в файле:`check_range_select.php`:

```
$min_ran = $_GET['min'];
$max_ran = $_GET['max'];
    if ($max_ran == "" || $min_ran == "")
    {
        echo "Вы не до конца заполнили данные";
    }
    else if ($max_ran < $min_ran)
    {
        echo "Ваше минимальное число больше максимального";
    }
    else if ($max_ran == $min_ran) {
        echo "Ваше минимальные числа одинаковы";
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: /Guess the number/matt.php');

        exit;
    }
?>
    <form action="/Guess the number/range select.php" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Попробовать снова" class='btn btn-success' >
    </form>
```

Внутри этого файла я помещаю данные формы в переменные и произвожу с ними условные проверки  `if\else if\else`, и если данные, введенные пользователем, удовлетворяют мои условия, то я перехожу на следующую страницу: `matt.php`
Внутри нее мне также необходимо работать с данными, которые пользователь ввел в первой форме, но я обнаружил, что форма очищается, после перехода на другую страницу.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы я мог использовать данные, которые заложены внутри первой `$_POST`?

Comment: Передавать это через GET параметры или хранить в СЕСИИ данные

Comment: Но выглядит это как-то всё странно само по себе. Зачем такие манипуляции? И почему нельзя сразу всё необзодимое заинклудить и передать внутри скрипта?

Comment: В данном случае надо использовать сессии

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я понимаю, что это можно сделать легче и оптимизированное, но я работаю с теми знаниями, что у меня есть на данный момент

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее рассказать, как это сделать? С помощью сессий или GET